# Where Infinispan store cache data?

Tags: caching, infinispan

What's the difference between infinispan local cache and distributed cache. I know that in local cache no cluster can be formed whereas in distributed cache we can form the cluster. My doubt is whether the distributed cache data will store in our running application heap or external to the application. Also, whether it is possible to obtain the data stored in infinispan running in one jvm by application running in another jvm.

Answer (score 3):

Infinispan stores the data in the application heap. It also can persist the data if you configure a CacheStore (for example a database). You have the details here: [Infinispan Persistence](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_persistence)

About the second question: yes, Infinispan know where the data is stored and fetches from other nodes (or jvms) if no copy is available local. If you need more details, you can check the documentation: [Infinispan Clustering](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_clustering)